# how to Remove Dynamically Created UIView and UILabel text?

Tags: ios, uiview

I am adding some dynamic UIView named as *cellSeparator and other UILabels...now what happen is when i again call this code then its rewrite the label text and overwrite on previously created label text...i am not very much aware to this ios development.so can anyone please tell me how can i remove this UIView dynamically before creating again?beacause UIView is dynamically created i dont know how to remove that UIview

```
  UILabel *indexLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, self.view.frame.size.height-150, self.view.frame.size.width/2,30)];
            [indexLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            indexLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            indexLabel.text = @"Details:-";
            indexLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.00];
            UILabel *tagLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, self.view.frame.size.height-120, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 30)];
            tagLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


            NSLog(@"LOg %@",imageId);
            NSLog(@"LOg %@",imageStyle);
            NSLog(@"LOg %@",imageType);
            NSLog(@"LOg %@",imageWeight);
            tagLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Id of Jewl Is:  %@",imageId];

            imageTypelabel= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, self.view.frame.size.height-90, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 30)];
            imageTypelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            imageTypelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Type of Jewl Is:  %@",imageType];
            imageStylelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, self.view.frame.size.height-60, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 30)];
            imageTypelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            imageStylelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The style of Jewl Is:  %@",imageStyle];
            imageWeightlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, self.view.frame.size.height-30, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 30)];
            imageStylelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            imageWeightlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The weight of Jewl Is:  %@",imageWeight];
            imageWeightlabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            imageWeightlabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            imageTypelabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            imageWeightlabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            tagLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            UIImage *imageBegin = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageBegin];


            UIView *cellSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,545, self.view.frame.size.width ,3)];
            cellSeparator.tag=1;
            [cellSeparator setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];       
            [cellSeparator setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTopLeft];    
            [cellSeparator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [self.view addSubview:cellSeparator];
```

Comment: remove sub views for superview when you call the second time?

Comment: 1. Not an Xcode question, 2. the class is called `UIView`, not `UIVIEW`.

Comment: To which view you are adding that label and imageView

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write a method to remove all the subviews of the view and modify this code according to your need.

```
- (void)removeSubviewsOfView
{
    NSArray *subViews = [self.view subviews];
    for(UIView *view in subViews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```